# DocumentDB connect timed out from EC2 spring boot app

Tags: java, mongodb, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-documentdb

I'm trying to connect programatically to the Amazon AWS DocumentDB but I receive connect timed out.

I deployed my spring boot app to the EC2. The EC2 is in the same VPC as my DocumentDB cluster.

MongoDB setup

```
Cluster identifier: mongodb
Instance identifier: mongodb ( available )
Region & AZ:  us-east-1c
Availability zone: us-east-1c
Engine version: 4.0.0
1 Instance: db.t3.medium
VPC Name (ID):  vpc-07630******afaa6
Instance endpoint: mongodb.ceupui6czrsm.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com
Username: admininstrator
Port: 27017
Certificate authority: rds-ca-2019
Security groups: sg-056d8***75f70ff1
```

EC2 instance

```
Availability Zone: us-east-1c
VPC ID:   vpc-07630******afaa6
```

I copied the jar and the pem file to the EC2 instance, in the same directory:

```
$ ls
documentdbmongo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  rds-ca-2019-root.pem
```

And I started as:

```
$ java -jar documentdbmongo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The error is always the same, connect timed out:

```
NFO 4524 --- [onaws.com:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : 
Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server mongodb.ceupui6czrsm.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:180) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:193) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:157) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:107) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/:na]
```

Log from the Mongo:

```
org.mongodb.driver.client                : 
MongoClient with metadata {"driver": 
{"name": "mongo-java-driver|sync", "version": "4.6.1"}, 
"os": {"type": "Linux", "name": "Linux", "architecture": "amd64", "version": "5.10.135-122.509.amzn2.x86_64"}, "platform": "Java/Red Hat, Inc./11.0.16+8-LTS"} created with settings 
MongoClientSettings{readPreference=ReadPreference{name=secondaryPreferred, hedgeOptions=null}, writeConcern=WriteConcern{w=null, wTimeout=null ms, journal=null}, retryWrites=false, retryReads=true, readConcern=ReadConcern{level=null}, credential=

MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='admininstrator', source='mongodb', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}, streamFactoryFactory=null, commandListeners=[], codecRegistry=ProvidersCodecRegistry{codecProviders=[ValueCodecProvider{}, BsonValueCodecProvider{}, DBRefCodecProvider{}, DBObjectCodecProvider{}, DocumentCodecProvider{}, IterableCodecProvider{}, MapCodecProvider{}, GeoJsonCodecProvider{}, GridFSFileCodecProvider{}, Jsr310CodecProvider{}, JsonObjectCodecProvider{}, BsonCodecProvider{}, EnumCodecProvider{}, com.mongodb.Jep395RecordCodecProvider@5398edd0]}, 

clusterSettings={hosts=[mongodb.ceupui6czrsm.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017], srvServiceName=mongodb, mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, requiredReplicaSetName='null', serverSelector='null', clusterListeners='[]', serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', localThreshold='30000 ms'}, socketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=0, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, heartbeatSocketSettings=
SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=10000, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, connectionPoolSettings=ConnectionPoolSettings{maxSize=100, minSize=0, maxWaitTimeMS=120000, maxConnectionLifeTimeMS=0, maxConnectionIdleTimeMS=0, maintenanceInitialDelayMS=0, maintenanceFrequencyMS=60000, connectionPoolListeners=[], maxConnecting=2}, 
serverSettings=ServerSettings{heartbeatFrequencyMS=10000, minHeartbeatFrequencyMS=500, serverListeners='[]', serverMonitorListeners='[]'}, sslSettings=SslSettings{enabled=true, invalidHostNameAllowed=false, context=null}, applicationName='null', compressorList=[], uuidRepresentation=UNSPECIFIED, serverApi=null, autoEncryptionSettings=null, contextProvider=null}
```

The config class:

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;
import com.mongodb.ReadPreference;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.connection.ConnectionPoolSettings;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Objects;

@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {


    public static final String SSL_CERTIFICATE = "rds-ca-2019-root.pem";
    public static final String KEY_STORE_TYPE = "JKS";
    public static final String KEY_STORE_PROVIDER = "SUN";
    public static final String KEY_STORE_FILE_PREFIX = "sys-connect-via-ssl-test-cacerts";
    public static final String KEY_STORE_FILE_SUFFIX = ".jks";
    public static final String DEFAULT_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD = "changeit";


    public static String userName = "admininstrator";
    public static String databaseName = "mongodb";

    public static String password = "p****";

    public static String clusterEndPoint = "mongodb.ceupui6czrsm.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com";


    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongoClient() throws Exception {


        setSslProperties();



        final MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(userName, databaseName, password.toCharArray());

        final MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                                                                .credential(credential)
                                                                .readPreference(ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred())
                                                                .retryWrites(false)
                                                                .applyToSslSettings(builder -> builder.enabled(true))
                                                                .applyToConnectionPoolSettings(connPoolBuilder ->
                                                                                                    ConnectionPoolSettings.builder()
                                                                                                                    .   maxSize(1).build()
                                                                                            )
                                                                .applyToClusterSettings(builder ->
                                                                        builder.hosts(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress(clusterEndPoint, 27017))
                                                                        )
                                                                )
                                                                .build();

        log.info("MongoClientSettings successfull. Returning MongoClient");

        return MongoClients.create(settings);
    }


    /**
     * This method sets the SSL properties which specify the key store file, its type and password.
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private static void setSslProperties() throws Exception {

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", createKeyStoreFile());
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", KEY_STORE_TYPE);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", DEFAULT_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD);
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the path of the Key Store File needed for the SSL verification during the IAM Database Authentication to
     * the db instance.
     *
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private static String createKeyStoreFile() throws Exception {
        return createKeyStoreFile(createCertificate()).getPath();
    }

    /**
     * This method generates the SSL certificate.
     *
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private static X509Certificate createCertificate() throws Exception {

        final CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

        final ClassLoader classLoader = MongoConfig.class.getClassLoader();
        final InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(SSL_CERTIFICATE);

        if (Objects.isNull(is)) {
            throw new Exception("SSL_CERTIFICATE settings error");
        }

        return (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(is);
    }

    /**
     * This method creates the Key Store File.
     *
     * @param rootX509Certificate - the SSL certificate to be stored in the KeyStore
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private static File createKeyStoreFile(final X509Certificate rootX509Certificate) throws Exception {
        final File keyStoreFile = File.createTempFile(KEY_STORE_FILE_PREFIX, KEY_STORE_FILE_SUFFIX);
        try (final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(keyStoreFile.getPath())) {
            final KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KEY_STORE_TYPE, KEY_STORE_PROVIDER);
            ks.load(null);
            ks.setCertificateEntry("rootCaCertificate", rootX509Certificate);
            ks.store(fos, DEFAULT_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
        }
        return keyStoreFile;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your security groups, so that your EC2 instance can reach the DocumentDB cluster on that port

Comment: Java code looks okay to me, as a previous user mentioned, can you check security groups and see if you can connect with mongo client from the EC2 instance?